# c++ declaring stl vector using type of befriending class as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    friend class B;
    struct model_struct {
       [...]
    }
}

template <typename T>
class B {
    func {
        typename vector<A<T>::model_struct > myVec;
    }
}
```

the vector declaration is giving me the following compile error:

error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template class std::vector’

error:   expected a type, got ‘ObjectExtraction::model_struct’

any ideas?

Comment: What is `func` supposed to be?

Comment: Have you tried putting the _typename_ before `A<T>::model_struct` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things appear to be missing:

- Semicolons at the end of class definitions
- The template argument in the friend declaration
- The `typename` specifier in the `vector` declaration

The latter is the problem that gave rise to the error.

I am unsure what the `func {...}` in the definition of `B` does; you may want to consider removing it.

Finally, you'll need a forward-declaration of the `B` template, so you can actually use it for the friend declaration in `A`.

Here is an attempt at correcting the code:

```
template <typename T>
class B; // Forward-declaration

template <typename T>
class A {
    friend class B<T>;  // template argument added
    struct model_struct {
       /*...*/
    };  // added semicolon
}; // semicolon added

template <typename T>
class B {
   /* Removed 'func'. */
   typename vector<typename A<T>::model_struct > myVec; // 'typename' added
};
```

Comment: so putting in the typename inside vector declaration fixed it.  Do I still need the typename before the vector?

Comment: @Mustafa No, you can remove that one.

Comment: Thank you very much and I did need the forward declaration to fix another error that came up.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify like this:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    friend class B;
    struct model_struct {
       [...]
    }
}

template <typename T>
class B {
    func {
        vector<typename A<T>::model_struct > myVec;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile due to the missing template argument in the `friend` declaration, and missing semicolons (apart from the `func` problem mentioned in the comments to the question).